# Is a holographic recorder able to capture a large full color picture?

Tags: optics, visible-light, hologram

Is it practical to attempt to build a 3D hologram generator that is full color and big enough to recreate a watermelon full size?  If so, is real-time control feasible?

Comment: Manufacturing production costings don't seem to be on-topic.

Comment: Indeed, @RedGrittyBrick is correct. (In the future, if you see something that you think might be off topic, don't forget to flag it as such!)

Comment: @gwentech Cost just seems to define an upper limit for building this device in industry. I see your question *on topic*. If you think so, please edit your question to remove the US dollar.

Comment: My thought is that this is asking about construction, not about a physical principle, and is still off topic. If it were asking something about the physics behind how holograms are produced, or about physical effects that might limit the size, then it'd be fine. Anyway, we'll see what other people think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my one day lab practice experience, I will cover the general part of your question.

**Color of hologram**

Compared to a conventional photo a [hologram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Holograph-record.svg/1000px-Holograph-record.svg.png) additionaly saves phase (of light wave) information. Depending on the viewport the wave reconstruction allows the observer the experience color 3D pictures. However this reconstruction has a flaw: the [chromatic abberation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Holomouse2.jpg) means color changes like a rainbow (color hologram on wiki) as can be seen in holograms [on a credit card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Smartcard2.png).
[image: mice hologram with chromatic abberation]

Holograms demand the same wavelength for reconstruction than creation. I do not know whether there is a procedure to capture real color holograms using 3 capturing wavelengths, better than the above shown mice from wiki.

**Cost of elements for a holographic recorder**

Cost of [elements for a hologram recorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram#Items_required): Using  laser of long coherence length(depth of focus), stable mechanics and environment, beam splitter, beam expander, a photobox full o sand and [holographic recording media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram#Holographic_recording_media), this is easiliy done below 30k US$\$$. Scale this up from my $5\cdot5\,$cm$^2$ using stronger beam expander. Your answer is **yes** but the question of the quality of the hologram remains. A proof is the initial linked picture of a mice, that is small compared to a water melon.